# Arraylist not adding java

Tags: java

I am doing a simple sch program to add friends, which is to add objects into an arraylist. I followed everything but my method befriend() doesn't seem to work.
When i manually test using the .add() in the main, it works. Where am i doing wrongly?

```
import java.util.*;
public class NetworkFriends {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here



     Person me = new Person("Aloysius", 1);

     ArrayList<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(me.getFriendList()));

     Person p1 = new Person("Gorgon", 2);
     Person p2 = new Person("Eddy", 3);

     me.befriend(p1);

     for(Person i : myList) {
         System.out.println("Name: " + i.getName());
     }
    }
}

class Person
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Person> friendList;
    private static int runningNum = 0;
    private static int friendsLimit = 5;
        private String degree;
        private int degreeNum;

    /* Constructor - 1 param */
    public Person(String name, int degreeNum)
    {
        //Implement your code here..
        //Initialize all necessary variable(s)
                this.name = name;
                friendList = new ArrayList<Person>(5);
                this.degree = degree;
                this.degreeNum = degreeNum;
}

public void befriend(Person p){
        //Implement your code here..

                ArrayList<Person> anotherList = new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(p.getFriendList()));

                for(Person i : friendList) {
                    if(!isFriend(this) && friendList.size() < 5) {
                            friendList.add(p);
                            anotherList.add(this);
                    }
                    else if(!isFriend(this) && friendList.size() == 5) {
                        System.out.println("Friends limit reached");
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.println("Already in friend list");
                    }
                }

    }
}

 public boolean isFriend(Person p){
        //Implement your code here..

                boolean isItAFriend = true;
                for(Person i : friendList) {
                    if(friendList.contains(p)) {
                        isItAFriend = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        isItAFriend = false;
                    }
                }
                return isItAFriend;

        }
```

Comment: I can tell you your isFriend method isn't doing what you think it is. But since this looks like a homework assignment, I'll instead highly recommend you take a few minutes and become familiar with using a debugger and use that instead, as it will quickly answer your questions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gAjIQc4bPU

Comment: What is this: `new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(p.getFriendList()));`? Why are you turning a list into an array into a list again? And (although you haven't shown the code) this creates a copy, so actions on the original have no effect on the copy.

Comment: Two things: 1) 'ArrayList<Person> anotherList = new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(p.getFriendList()));' is horrific. Don't write this kind of code. 2) The key point is you want to deduplicate the friends with each other. Using Set instead of List will make it very easy. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `foreach` loop in your befriend method. You are creating a new `Person` with the constructor that creates a empty friend list with an initial size of 5, but is still empty.

In your `befriend` method, you then are looping for each friend in this empty list. So the code within the loop will not be executed and the friend is never added to a list.

I suspect you want to do something like this: (and as this looks like homework I will only give you pseudo-code)

1. Is the person already a friend

   - Yes - nothing needs to be done or give feedback and return
   - No - Continue
2. Have they reached their friend limit

   - Yes - display feedback and return
   - No - Continue
3. Add the friend

Comment: which loop are you referring to?

Comment: very clear and detailed answer. @Aloysius: one way to debug issues like this is to put log (in your case System.out.println) at every code branching (if, for, while...). You will know which path the code goes through, and see the issue better.